# how to import project with remote git access jbpm

Tags: docker, jboss, jbpm, business-process-management

I'm trying to import a local project into mySpace in the business central following the steps of the tutorial, but for some reason the file:///{path} format is not working and I do not have a .git repo formed even after following the steps. Has anyone had this problem before? Appreciate the feedback.

Edit: btw my pathing is file:///C:\Users\ilija.ristovski\Downloads\business-application\business-application-kjar so I could be messing this up

Comment: which tutorial?

Comment: hey thanks for the interest but i fixed my issue. btw the tutorial i was talking about was from the main documentation where it takes you through the process step by step

Comment: @IleRistovski, write, please, how you solved that.

Comment: @coder-coder just use git daemon --export-all and make sure the slashes are all "/"